# A CMS for an Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

More of a question than a problem but I'm wondering if anyone has attempted or seen the use of a CMS for an Alexa Skill. I'm imagining a simple FAQ based Alexa skill. The JSON for the intent would have to be generated elsewhere or at least supplied elsewhere. The idea is that through the CMS you could supply the intent and also the response. I know this is very lose but I'm kind of feeling out if anyone has done anything with this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this project?
https://www.hackster.io/tom-harrigan280/alexawp-20a282

Github repo is here:
https://github.com/tomharrigan/AlexaWP

I believe it close to what you are looking for. It uses Wordpress as the source of content for responses to Alexa requests.